# View man pages via Emacs

Tags: linux, bash, emacs, man

I basically want what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644163/how-to-view-man-pages-using-emacs-when-invoking-man-command-in-command-line) asks for. Unfortunately, its answers don't work.

For example, when I do what [its most-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645309/5091709) says, and enter `man echo`, Emacs opens up and the mini buffer says:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: \(man\ \"echo\"\)
```

The only window in Emacs is blank.

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406721/using-emacs-for-pager) doesn't help either.

I normally use Emacs with its GUI but want to view man pages in the terminal.

Setting the variable `$PAGER` to `emacs` doesn't work either. First of all, it's empty or unset by default. If I change it to `emacs`, subsequent calls to `man` do result in Emacs (GUI) opening but the scratch buffer is shown, just as if I would normally launch Emacs (I disabled the welcome page, that's why the scratch buffer is shown).

I know that I can launch Emacs, press `C-x`, enter `man`, and then enter the name of the man page I want to read. But that takes quite some time and just entering `man <page name>` into a terminal is much faster.

My computer runs Ubuntu 16.04 (with Linux 4.4.0) and GNU Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: What does `type emacs` return on your system?

Comment: @choroba `emacs is /usr/bin/emacs`

Answer (score 2):

Starting a new Emacs every time you want to view a man page is an unusual workflow. Most commonly people prefer to re-use a running Emacs:

```
emacsclient --no-wait -e '(man "man")'
```

If you truly insist on swimming against the flow, you can do

```
emacs -Q --eval '(progn (man "man") (delete-window))'     # not recommended
```

See also [Using Emacs for $PAGER?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8406721/850781)

Comment: But it is the workflow I like. I often use several Emacs windows. I don't use Emacs as a window manager, there already is a window manager built into my system. Your command does actually open the man page in an existing Emacs instance. Is it possible to just launch a new Emacs instance in the terminal the command is executed in?

Comment: @UTF-8: Using a single emacs instance with many windows (called "frames" in emacs lisp) has numerous benefits (e.g., dynamic completion can use buffers in another frame). It also consumes less resources. However, see edit.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I added `-nw` so it doesn't launch the GUI. It opens 2 frames: i.imgur.com/yA0E4fC.png Is it possible to let it execute a C-x 0 automatically so only the frame with the man page buffer is shown?

Comment: just add what `C-x 0` does to the `--eval`

Comment: I tried it but I can't seem to figure out how to separate the commands: https://pastebin.com/pn0jsL7B The man page is opened by all of them but the other commands aren't executed. When I evaluate any of them in the scratch buffer, they work.

Comment: use `progn`, see edit I made 15 minutes ago

Comment: The only difference is that the scratch buffer is empty now. So it doesn't say `;; This buffer is for notes [...]` but there still is a frame for the scratch buffer.

Comment: the code in the answer works for me with and without `-nw`

Comment: I ran it on my raspi which has a different Emacs configuration and doesn't use the GUI. It behaves exactly the same as on my laptop (but I don't have to pass `-nw`), so still 2 frames present.

Comment: you can try replacing `delete-window` with `delete-other-windows`

Comment: It's getting weirder. I now would have expected the same thing as just before or the man page buffer to vanish. However, it's just like before that: 2 frames (one fore the scratch buffer and one for the man page buffer) and the scratch buffer contains the `;; This buffer is for notes [...]` text. I now typed both variants (`delete-window` and `delete-other-windows`) several times instead of copying it to make 100% sure there isn't some weird spelling mistake or invisible character which messes it up in there.

Comment: Please do not confuse frames, windows and buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a shell session.
Here is how I view man pages in emacs:
I use a package called Shell-pop (available in Melpa)
I configured it to use eshell and I call it with Ctrl-T.
I just type the man (program I want info on) and it pops into anothe window (horizontally or vertically, depending on your set-up)